# Linking ajax document

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

first of all thanks for reading.

Hi have a form which I'm trying to collect data through Ajax.
 I did it putting the ajax code into the `<script> </script>` tags and it worked fine. But when i moved it to a folder (js/registrarciu_ajax.js) and added `<script src="js/registrarciu_ajax.js"> </script`> it hasn't been working!.

Index.php linking tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/registrarciu_ajax.js"></script>
```

index.php form:

```
            <form method="POST" id="form-registrar-ciu" action="" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre_apellido">Nombre_Apellido</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre_apellido" id="nombre_apellido" placeholder="Phillip_Rousseau">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dni">N° DNI/Pasaporte</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="42393402">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edad" id="edad" for="edad" placeholder="Edad">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="residencia" id="residencia" for="residencia" placeholder="LS/SF/LV">
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-success" id="registrar-btn" type="button" value="Registrar"> Registrar ciudadano>
        </form>
```

Ajax code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#registrar-btn").click(function(){
    var nombre_apellido = $("#nombre_apellido").val();
    var dni = $("#dni").val();
    var edad = $("#edad").val();
    var residencia = $("#residencia").val();
    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    var dataString = 'nombre_apellido1='+ nombre_apellido + '&dni1='+ dni + '&edad1='+ edad + '&residencia1='+ residencia;
    if(nombre_apellido==''||dni==''||edad==''||residencia=='')
    {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    }
    else
    {
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "registrar_ciu.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
        alert(result);
        }
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

I don't think it's necessary to put the .php file who refer the ajax code, because it works fine. The problem is that when I click the form's button, it doesn't refer to the .js file which is in the 'js' folder (but it works if the ajax code is in the same file of the form, into 'scripts' tag>

Comment: Are you sure the `js` file is loaded? (Have a look in your console. do you get a `404` error?)

Comment: Sounds like you got the URL wrong.

Comment: Write a `console.log` somewhere to see what happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not, then simply add this before the script tag you are calling the js file from

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or any other jquery library you prefer; You need jQuery library in order to run jQuery

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!. I already had a JQuery library which was loaded on the JS file, but with this (from googleapis) it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped you ;)